# Application is not responding - create exception?

Tags: android, crashlytics

My application sometimes stops with message:

> Application is not responding. Would you like to close it?

I know it is problem with something time consuming on UI thread. But I have no idea what it's causing - this problem is shown maybe in 1% of all runnings.

For bug report I'm using system Crashylitcs - it's very good but doesn't catch any error when application is closing this way - because there is nothing to catch.

It is possible to create exception when application crashes like this? Or how could I reload application after this kind of crash (it would be just temporary solution until I will find what the real problem is).

Usually the bug will appear when application is bring back to front - but in "onResume" there are no time consuming functions.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Don't try to catch/log this bug. Just resolve it, it's absolutely not normal that your app "is not responding". You have a leak somewhere, If it's not onResume it can be onStop/Pause/Whatever

Comment: avoid multiple task wait for previous execution end.

Comment: about code: sorry but after start it does a lot of things and it would be really long... it shows map, downloads at least 5 different xml files from network and a lot of other things... and I have no idea where from all of this things could be problem so I can't post it all. And yes somewhere is the leak but I want to find out where - there is really a lot of possible places where the problem can be. That's why I want to catch it.

Comment: it could be problem that I have more than one AsyncTask running? But - why it just crash 1% of the time?

Answer (score 2):

ANR-Watchdog (https://github.com/SalomonBrys/ANR-WatchDog) detects Android ANR (Application Not Responding) error and throws a meaningful exception. It sets up a "watchdog" timer that will detect when the UI thread stops responding. When it does, it raises an error with all threads stack traces (main first). Moreover, a crash handler like Crashlytics can intercept it and handle it the way it needs.

Answer (score 1):

Is you application published on Google Play? Google play console do log this type of problems. It's called ANR (application not responding). You can even check threads state there and identiy you problem.

Comment: No, sadly it's not. This application is for special use where we can't put it into google play :-/ that's why i'm using 3rd party debug report system (Crashylitcs)

Answer (score 0):

For your code optimisation try/catch have big cost of memory, try to use only if is mandatory. Also when you have "Application is not responding. Would you like to close it?" probably you make a procest which has a high cost of memory like multipe bitmaps and so on... so you have to optimize your code to consume less memory especially for weaker devices

Comment: It occurs usually after video has been played - but it's always the same video on the same device (or the same type of device). Also the video has just a few MB and RAM has a lot of free space. It's always the same - after fresh start of device, the same video, same applications... That is what's weird about it :-/ But yes I'm also using a lot of try/catch but why 99% of times works flawlessly and just 1% it stops...?

Comment: it depends on the OS allocating process, try to force gc but it is not good practice, also try to remove try/catch blocks that is not necessary